# Custom List Search not Working

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, sharepoint-search

## Problem

The in-list search functionality does **not** work for any custom lists on our site. I'm not sure what is causing this. Document Libraries work just fine for search. It seems to only be the custom lists.

### What I have

- SharePoint 2013
- Site Owner Permissions

### What I don't have

- Server Side Access
- Permission to use any custom code or 3rd part

Comment: What's the error message it's showing., did you check the error logs

Comment: There is no error message showing. Unless you are asking for error messages that are hidden elsewhere?